# Angular 2 with Typescript pluggable component for javascript projects

Tags: typescript, angular

I just want to know that, is it possible to create **pluggable component in Angular 2 with Typescript** for JavaScript project? I know that **any JavaScript code is valid Typescript code**, but what if you have **already developed** your JavaScript(ES5) project, and you want certain modules like **Drag-Drop Module** or **Form Validator Module** or **Multiple Choice Questions(MCQ)** Module (Developed in Angular 2 TS) for existing project?

I really don't know whether Angular 2(Typescript) is really suitable to such kind of **pluggable module creation** or not? OR is it like that, Angular 2 is used for creating **SPA**s only?

Since Angular 2 components have their own **life-cycle** and JavaScript functions executes **sequentially**. then **how the co-ordination possible**?

If you know any kind of example(if it is possible) the please help me out? I'll really appreciate your responses!! (I tried on the net but didn't get any proper solution)

Answer (score 0):

You can develop Angular2 components and directives to be used in other Angular2 applications. Angular2 is not suitable to build libraries for plain JavaScript applications.

You can use TypeScript without Angular2 though. Your JS is already valid TypeScript. Just include the TypeScript code into your JS code base and build them together.

Comment: thanks, I'll definitely try to TS code in JS. Again what if it is **already created web site**, and I want to use Angular 2 TS component for **form validation** OR **site navigation** etc. how feasible it is to go with Angular 2 TS?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "form validation". Angular form validation only works in Angular components. You can use Angular router for navigation in an Angular application but not individually outside Angular2.

Comment: **"form validation"** in the sense, <form> field user **input field** validations using Angular component.